# Solved: Checkout cart components loading weird

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, cart, frontend

we have a serious problem with the cart-view in our shop: https://www.murergrej.dk/checkout/cart/

- Problem 1: Not all buttons are clickable anymore.
- Problem 2: The message "Free shipping" is shown all the time.
- Problem 3: The right sidebar is missing its content, which is the overview of the different prices, the calculation of the shipping price and the possibility to add a discount code.

**Situation:**
We had the website on a development server and moved it to the live server. The problem wasn't on the dev-server present.
All JS files seem to be loaded and we can't identify any relevant error messages, what makes debugging really uncomfortable.

**What I tried so far:**

- Deactivating modules installed after we moved
- Disable custom JS
- Switch from production back to development mode
- Deploy, deploy, deploy (of course with setup:upgrade, di:compile, cache:clean/flush)
- Reindex (what shouldn't do any difference)

Any new perspective/idea on how to approach the debugging would be a great help.

Thank you very much!

Robert

**EDIT**

A module from a third party was altered by them, which caused the error. I will contact them, so that they fix the bug.

It is/was caused by cached jquery-data.